# Is there a Gnome-Shell Auto-Move-Windows equivalent in Unity/Compiz?

Tags: unity, 11.10, compiz, windows, workspaces

I want that when a certain application is started that it automatically moves to workspace 2 ...

I already tried the Compiz Window Placement plugin but this only works for start-up applications.

In Gnome-Shell there is the extension auto-move-windows but for Unity/Compiz I can't find an equivalent.

Can you please help?

Comment: I just found out how to do it, maybe it will help someone!

Open Terminal and install CompizConfig-Settings Manager:

    sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

Start **CompizConfig-Settings Manager** and **'Window Placement'** in the 'Window Managment' section.

Go to the tab called **'Fixed Window Placement'** and create a new entry in the section **'Windows with fixed viewport'**

In the first box enter `'name=appname'` where appname is you desired application.

Enter desired **workspace row in Viewport-X-Position** and desired **workspace column in Viewport-Y-Position**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `devilspie` for that. Here is a nice [How-To](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2007/07/25/how-to-set-default-workspace-size-and-window-effects-in-gnome/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use wmctrl. Here is the man page : http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl